# pickle (or pickle like) serialization in python for objects with members that have custom file formats and serialization logic

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, catboost

I need to serialize python classes that contain fields that require custom serialization (for example: catboost models, but there are many other examples)

in simple cases I provide a save and load functions that pickle all the other fields, and save the model to a separate file

however, this solution wouldn't work for cases where this class is part of a larger class that needs to be serialized (unless requiring each class to implement these save and load methods)

is there some way with pickle (or some other serialization framework) to save some of the nested objects to a separate file?

Comment: You can write a custom serializer and register it with pickle. Then you can store everything in the one pickle file without the need for a separate file. Though if for some reason you insist on having a separate file, your custom serializer could  (though I would not recommend it) write the data to its own separate file, and you could then store the filename in the pickle file.

Comment: do you have reference for using custom serializers with pickle?
the reason for using a separate file is that these objects provide a method for serializing to file, but not to a buffer or something similar

Comment: It's all covered in the `pickle` documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html .